# loading resource bundle from another java project

Tags: jsf, resourcebundle, modularity

i want to load i18 resource bundles from another project ,
i managed to load 18n messages properties files from resources directory in my webApp project , but what i realy need is to have all my configuration files reside in another project.

here's my faces-config :

```
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <application>
      <resource-bundle>
         <base-name>messages</base-name>
         <var>msgs</var>
      </resource-bundle>
      <locale-config>
         <default-locale>fr</default-locale>
      </locale-config>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

messages files are location in my webapp resources directory.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the jar of other project in you project's class path.
That jar should be having property file.